# Why Server says - 404 - File or directory not found. while file exist?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, http-status-code-404, flowplayer

I want to play an mp4 file using flowplayer and ASP.NET.
my video file placed at location :

```
http://domain.com/website/files/dd/dd21f5c6-8721-4f12-81a7-0afb9d7d7bfa.mp4
```

but my flow player don't play the file.

**when i type this address in address bar i got following error :**

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

The file exist in the path specified.

can anyone help me about this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good chance your webserver is not configured to serve mp4 files. You can add the mime type to your server.

Here you can read how to do this in windows IIS 7 [http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc753281(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc753281%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

addition, a better link maybe:
http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx

Comment: when i add mime type .mp4 - video/mp4 server make file downloadable but flowplayer don't play file

Comment: well then you're one step further! I don't know anything about flowplayer, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Reasons for this error are:
 1. File may not be in the specified location.
 2. The server may not recognize the specified type of file.

Comment: File exist in the specified location.
but about second one could you explain more?
when i add MIME Type server give me download.
but flow playe don't play the file

Answer (score 1):

Some hostingproviders place another .htaccess file deep somewhere in your media library, which in my case contained this:

```
<Files *.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

Removing this file did the trick for me.

Docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#Deny